# Rename group of consecutive columns efficiently in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, rename

I'm looking for an efficient way to rename several columns.

I have a dataframe that looks like the following.

```
id  sdf  dir  fki 
1   3    4    2
2   5    2    1
3   4    1    2
```

I want to rename columns sdf, dir, and fki.

I know I could do so like this:

```
df <- df %>% 
rename(newname1 = sdf, 
       newname2 = dir, 
       newname3 = fki)
```

With the amount of columns I have, it is taking a long time to type the names of the columns I would like to replace.

Ideally, I would like to create a vector with names:

```
newcolumns <- c("newname1", "newname2", "newname3")
```

And then specify that these should replace the column names in the dataframe, starting with column sdf. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rename_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      rename_at(vars(-id), ~ newcolumns)
```

-output

```
#   id newname1 newname2 newname3
#1  1        3        4        2
#2  2        5        2        1
#3  3        4        1        2
```

---

Or with `rename_with`

```
df %>%
   rename_with(~ newcolumns, -id)
```

---

Or pass a `named` vector and use `!!!` in `rename`

```
df %>%
    rename(!!! setNames(names(df)[-1], newcolumns))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
names(df)[-1] <- newcolumns
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, sdf = c(3L, 5L, 4L), dir = c(4L, 2L, 
1L), fki = c(2L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: With rename_at(), how do I subset columns like you're able to do with base R? For example, if I am trying to do this for columns 24:45 in a dataframe.

Comment: @melbez it is just `df %>% rename_at(24:45, ~ newcolumnnames)`